# android Text to Speech of a toast message

Tags: android, android-toast, google-text-to-speech

I am getting an error with the conversion of the text to speech in android studio. I have initialised the code but it still returns no voice outputs. The code is as follows.

```
else if((match.contains("yes") || match.contains("yeah")) && defsele) {
        //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Default selection is done and program is starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //toast.show();
        defsele=false;
        switch (progno) {
            case 1:
                //Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"The default settings for cotton cycle is done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                //toast1.show();
                String cotton = "The cotton program is starting with the default values";
                tts.speak(cotton, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                soak=true;
                soakdef();
                break;
```

The `tts.speak` gets deprecated and does not function. How can I make this work? The initialisation code is as follows:

```
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
  @Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Log.d("Speech", "OnInit - Status ["+status+"]");
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        Log.d("Speech","Success");
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextToSpeech textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                            //your text
                            String textToSpeechStr = "Hello";

                            //status is success / 0
                            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                                //speech starts

                                textToSpeech.speak(textToSpeechStr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                            }
                        
                    }
                });
```

Comment: nope, the code automatically comments itself. is there anyway i can just initialize the api and convert multiple sentences using just the "tts.speak()" function??